# how to convert Java into UML?

Tags: java, uml, diagram

I have been searching on the site but I can't find something that feels right. I want to rewrite this java code to UML diagram.

```
public class Fotbollslag {
    private Spelare[] lag=new Spelare[30];

public void läggTillSpelare(Spelare spelare){
lag[antalSpelare]=spelare;
antalSpelare++;
```

Comment: Worth to notice is it that in the array it can both be String, and Int

Comment: Do you have a question?  "I want _X_" is not a question.

Comment: Yes how to convert this java Code into a Uml :)

Comment: That's not a question either.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: This piece of code is even incomplete. I recommend to read a book on how to do that and come up with a real question then.

Comment: Yes i know but i know how to convert the rest of the code its just the array i really dont understand and i have searched alot.

Answer (score 0):

Take as example the following code:

```
public class Employee {
    private static String department = "R&D";
    private int empId;
    private Employee(int employeeId) {
        this.empId = employeeId;
    }
    public static String getEmployee(int emplId) {
        if (emplId == 1) {
            return "idiotechie";
        } else {
            return "Employee not found";
        }
    }
    public static String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
}
```

The above example is an example of `Employee` Class, it has two `private` attributes of types `int` and `String`, one `Constructor`, and two `public` methods of type `String`. In UML, we have different notations for different scopes such as `private, public, package and protected`.
The UML notations are:

`public: (+), private: (-), package: (~) and protected: (#)`
For the mentioned code above, the UML class diagram would look like that:

[image: UML Class Diagram]
<sub>(source: [i2.wp.com](https://i2.wp.com/idiotechie.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/classdiagram.jpg?resize=220%2C205))</sub>

As you can see, a `Class diagram` looks like a table, it is divided into three parts:
The upper part, which contains the `Class name`, the middle part, which contains the `attributes`, and lastly, the lower part, which contains the `methods(functions)`.

The name of the `Class` is usually Bold, the middle cell of the table, is the section of the `attributes` of the `Class`, and the bottom part is the part you write your `methods`. So a correct notation of writing an `attribute` would be first give the notation of the scope of the attribute (`-` if `private`, `+` if `public`), then the name of the attribute(`empId` in our `Employee` case), separate it by colon(`:`), then the type of the attribute (`String` or `int` for example), and in case it is initialized already, so you also write the value of this attribute. for `methods` it is the same story. In you question you don't have any relations between classes, so I didn't include any relationship explanations.
I recommend you to read some more about `UML` diagrams in general and can you convert code into `UML Class diagrams`, you can visit [this link](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-reference.html).

Edit:

I've just noticed you mentioned in the comments that you don't know how to represent an `array` in your UML diagram. It wasn't clear from your first question, but here's how it should be done in your example:

`-lag[0..29] : Spelare`

Explaination: notice that the visibility of your `array` is `private`, therefore the notation is `-`. Right after the visibility, we write the name of the `array`, the initial size of it(in your case, size is 30, therefore, indexes `[0..29]`, separated by colon, we write the type of the array, which in your case is `Spelare`.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I've edited my answer, check if it answering your question

Comment: @DanielHaugen forgot to tag you :/

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right you just have trouble showing the array. This is what you would do:

[image]

You just put the bounds in square brackets right after the type. And since it seems your array is fixed to 30 you just place `[30]`. Else you could specify any multiplicities as usual with the `..` range operator.

Comment: the public method laggTillSpelare should have a `void` return type.

Comment: @rags2riches Maybe. The OP seems to have drowned anyway. And - if there's nothing specified (as above) this IS `void`. `void` is just another word for empty or nothing.

Comment: and you should include the return type, whether it is a `String` type, an `int` type or any other type, including `void`. Unless you have re-written the UML rules or have a solid reference to look up to, since I have found nothing that says otherwise or that treats the `void` type differently than any other types in UML. As a software developer, I want to know the return type if I want to make sense out of the design/architecture which the UML model implies.

Comment: P. 117 of UML 2.5.1: _[<visibility>] <name> ‘(‘ [<parameter-list>] ‘)’ [‘:’ [<return-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] [‘{‘ <oper-property> [‘,’ <oper-property>]* ‘}’]]_ The `void` keyword is specific to C-like languages to mimic a "no return value". Other languages use different concepts. E.g. Pascal uses `procedure` (no return value) and `function` which requires the return type. Python for example does not enforce anything and just decides at run time. You need to get out of your Java drawer and look at the world as something quite large.

Comment: Stick to your business qwerty and to the question at hand. The question shares an example of Java code and you should include the return type `void` in the UML class diagram. That's it.